# getting wrong answer on a uva online judge problem(problem tag 10056)

Tags: c

Here is the [problem link](https://onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=997). I don't know why uva is showing wrong answer. For comparsion, I downloaded a solution and tried manually for many test cases. My code gives the same answer. Where is the problem?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main()
{
    int t;
    scanf("%d", &t);

    while (t--)
    {
        int x, n, a;
        double b, sum1 = 0, sum3 = 0;
        scanf("%d %lf %d", &n, &b, &a);

        if (b > 0) {
            x = a - 1;

            double re = (pow(1 - b, x) * b) / (1 - ((pow(1 - b, x + n) * b) / (pow(1 - b, x) * b)));
            printf("%.4lf\n", re);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("0.0000\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you know the exact input you can use a debugger to step through your code to figure out when and where and hopefully why you get the wrong results. But for good debugging, it also helps if you have good habits, like using semantically and descriptive names for your variables, don't create long and complex one-line statements or expressions, have good documentation and comments in the code, saying not only what you're doing but also *why*. Good habits that online judge/competition site will *not* teach you (they tend to do the opposite, actively promote bad habits)

Comment: Also please try to make your question *self contained*, by copy-pasting the "assignment" text into the question itself. Links can go stale, disappear or their contents might change.

Answer (score 0):

Try to `return 0` at the end. There is a convention that if a program has no errors, it returns 0 at the end. Some verification softwares check if your code has run successfully by looking at it's return value.

Comment: Since the C99 standard, that ending `return 0;` is implicit.

Comment: Then I've been wasting a line of code in every program for years! Thank you for the info.

Comment: Wikipedia article says user solution in C should be in C89. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UVa_Online_Judge

Answer (score 0):

info:

```
pow( doubleValue, 0 ) = 1
pow( doubleValue, 1 ) = doubleValue
```

the expression:

```
pow(1-probableWin,x )
```

where `x` is 1-1 = 0 (first player per your code)

```
pow(1-probableWin,x )
```

where `x` is 1 results in 1-probableWin (my idea for first player)

multiplying the above by:

```
*probableWin
```

where `x` is 0 results in 0 per the OPs code

```
*probableWin
```

where `x` is 1 results in (1-probableWin) * probableWin which is much better.

Suggest using a debugger and walking through the code, to determine where things are going wrong.

BTW: strongly suggest that long calculation of `re` be broken into (say) 4 or 5 statements so you can see the result of each expression.